# Как обратиться к элементу массива по его id? vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

Есть массив:

```
state() {
    return {
    items: [...Array(8)].map((n, i) => ({
        id: `${i + 1}`
      }))
    }
   }
```

Мне нужно получить ссылку на элемент массива по его id, то есть обратиться к нему. Этот код пишу в let slide. Выводил slide в консоль - получил undefined, что подтверждает неверное обращение к элементу

```
getters: {
openSlide(state, n) {
      // Получение ссылки на элемент
      let slide = state.items[n.id]
      // Определение расстояния от начала страницы до нужного элемента
      let top = window.scrollY + slide.getBoundingClientRect().y;
      // Перемотка
      window.scrollTo(0, top)
    }
   }
```

[image: Такой подход тоже вернул undefined]

[image: Массив]

[image: лог]
[image: все плохо]

Comment: `[...Array(8)]` - что это у Вас? Такая конструкция выведет 8 раз `undefined`

Comment: я так создал массив, который потом итерирую через v-for, получаю 8 дивов с уникальным id. Если обращаюсь по конкретному индексу все работает, но мне нужно обращаться не к статике(конкретному индексу или id), а к динамике(изменяемому id в зависимости от того, на какой заголовок кликнул. Если нужен весь код - могу предоставить

Comment: У вас массив объектов, значит получать нужно объект по условию: `state.items.find(x => x.id === n.id)`

Comment: Alex, к сожалению, такая конструкция так же выдает undefined, хотя идея с поиском объекта кажется правильной, возможно синтаксис нужен немного другой? приложил скрин кода

Comment: Тогда проверяйте, что у вас действительно хранится в объектах. Код из первой функции должен генерировать массив `[{ id : "1" }, { id : "2" }, { id : "3" }, ...]`. Судя по синтаксису в n должен прийти объект вида `{ id : "3"}`. Сделайте `console.log("params", state.items, n)` и посмотрите, что там хранится на самом деле, возможно мои предположения не верны и код нужно будет подправить исходя из реальных данных - большая вероятность, что в `n` хранится что-то другое, а не объект.

Comment: Добавил скрин элементов массива из расширения браузера vue, а также скрин с результатом указанного вами кода

Comment: У вас выходит `n` пустым, значит в него не передавались нужные данные для поиска. Обратите внимание как это делается в документации: [Геттеры | Vuex. Стиль обращения как к методам](https://vue3js.cn/vuex/ru/guide/getters.html#%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BA-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BC) и попробуйте так же.

Comment: документация не помогла, вроде бы попытался реализовать как там, но решить задачу это не помогло. Уже истерика(

Comment: Единственный вариант, когда мне удается получить результат приложил в скрине, однако там приходится вручную указывать индекс(конкретный, не динамический)

Comment: @Альберт Посмотрите пример в ответе, может поможет. Вам по факту нужно получать тогда не объект из state, а DOM элемент страницы. Для этого надо помечать элементы на страницы, либо через id как в примере, либо через refs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const { createApp } = Vue
const { createStore } = Vuex

const store = createStore({
  state () {
    return {
      items: [...Array(8)].map((n, i) => ({
        id: `${i + 1}`
      }))
    }
  },
  getters: {
    openSlide: state => id => {
      let slide = document.getElementById(id);
      let top = window.scrollY + slide.getBoundingClientRect().y;
      window.scrollTo(0, top);
    }
  }
})

const app = createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      store: store
    }
  }
});
app.use(store);
app.mount('#app');
```

```css
#app {
   min-height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex@4.0.0/dist/vuex.global.js"></script>

<div id="app">
    <div v-for="item in store.state.items">
        <div :id="item.id">{{ item.id }}</div>
    </div>
    <br />
    Scroll to:
    <span v-for="item in store.state.items">
        <button @click="store.getters.openSlide(item.id)">{{ item.id }}</button>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: C небольшой адаптацией под мои компоненты все заработало! Спасибо вам огромное, очень сильно помогли, безумно рад)